# excel vba char(10) with special string value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range with data and I am concatenating with line function and I want the output as follow

Range("A1:A3") has A,B,C and I want the output in single cell as

```
-A
-B
-C
```

I am using following code; somehow it is not giving me desired output. Can anyone look into this and assist?

```
Dim X As String,cell as Range
For Each Cell in Range("A1:A3")
  If(Len(cell.value)>0) Then
  X="-" & X & CHAR(10) & Cell.Value
End If
Next
Range("B1").Value= X

Range("B1").WrapText = True
Range("B1").Columns.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
X = X & "-" & cell.Value & Chr(10)
```

in full:

```
Sub ab_notsonull()
Dim X As String, cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A1:A3")
  If (Len(cell.Value) > 0) Then
  X = X & ("-" & cell.Value & Chr(10))
End If
Next
Range("B2").Value = Left$(X, Len(X) - 1)
Range("B2").WrapText = True
Range("B2").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: ... and probably remove the last character after the end of the loop using `Left(X, Len(X) - 1)`?  (To get rid of the final LF and avoid the cell thus displaying one blank "row" at the end.)  Or, probably easier, put the LF at the start of the concatenation and just use `Mid(x, 2)` when placing the value into the cell.

Comment: Your `Mid(X, Len(X), 1) = vbNullString` doesn't actually do anything, because the length of `vbNullString` is 0.  Assigning something to the `Mid` of a string only changes the number of characters determined by the lesser of the length parameter, the number of characters in the replacement string, and the number of characters to the end of the string.  You need to use `X = Left(X, Len(X) - 1)` to actually get rid of a character from `X`.

Comment: Yes, the Operator trick didn't work for the null replacement (poor testing). Opted for the string Left$ over the slower variant Left.